# ffmpeg changed safe option again?

Tags: ubuntu, ffmpeg

So in a previous version of ffmpeg it introduced a -safe 0 or -safe 1 option. I discovered this as I had a bash script that used ffmpeg with absolute paths i.e. in /dev/shm/. For the last 6 months or so I have worked around this by using the -safe 0 option.

Today while playing around I found that the latest version of ffmpeg in Ubuntu 16.10 returns 
    Option safe not found
when trying to use the -safe flag.

Did they finally decide to do away with the -safe option? Or is this a mis-build?